# How to use/set stopDelegation with jointjs paper options (basing on Angular 6 Kitchensink sample)

Tags: jointjs

I'm trying to use that "new" stopDelegation feature. I want to provide a "readonly" view of the paper and am nearly done - last thing missing is movability (drag) of the paper. Well, it is movable, but not when grabbing an element/shape/link. 
How is that option supposed to use?
I'm actually using v2.4.0 trial (Angular 6).

According to the documentation my guess was "stopDelegation" is a property of CellView.InteractivityOptions (or ElementView.InteractivityOptions). But that doesn't seem to work.

```js
    const self = this;
    const paper = (this.paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
      width: 1000,
      height: 1000,
      gridSize: 10,
      drawGrid: true,
      model: graph,
      cellViewNamespace: appShapes,
      defaultLink: <joint.dia.Link>new appShapes.app.Link(),
      interactive: function(cellView, event) {
        return {
          linkMove: self.isEditable,
          labelMove: self.isEditable,
          arrowheadMove: self.isEditable,
          vertexMove: self.isEditable,
          vertexAdd: self.isEditable,
          vertexRemove: self.isEditable,
          useLinkTools: self.isEditable,
          elementMove: self.isEditable,
          addLinkFromMagnet: self.isEditable,
          stopDelegation: self.isEditable
        } as joint.dia.CellView.InteractivityOptions;
      }
    }));
```

When `self.isEditable == false`, the paper should be movable when grabbing an element, but it isn't (it's still only movable when pointing on a void place on the paper).

(I also had to tweak rappis.d.ts a bit to allow interactive to be a function returning a `CellView.InteractivityOptions` object...).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?
Or isn't it intended/designed to use it that way (to allow moving of the paper only instead of a parent "element")?

Answer (score 1):

The stopDelegation property is relevant to embedded elements only.  Since paper is not "parent" to any elements, the interactivity can never be delegated to the paper.  The locking of the paper movement is a Rappid PaperScroller feature.

[Rappid PaperScroller](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v3.1/ui.html#ui.PaperScroller)

```
    var paperScroller = new joint.ui.PaperScroller({
        paper: paper,
        cursor: 'grab'
    });

    paperScroller.lock();
```

Comment: But let's say i want to set stopDelegation to a particular type of cell, where can I do that?